# Even Integers and Odd Integers count with Switch Case

Tags: java, int, switch-statement

I was asked to write a program that takes 5 numbers between 1-10, and find out how many of them are even and how many are odd using the free-fall approach of the Switch-Case statement. I have written the code, and I have declared variables within a local scope wherein the same switch case lies, so I don't think it's a problem about block scope. If numbers are odd (1,3,5,7,9) then the odd counter variable (oc) is incremented. Same happens for the even numerals. If numbers are not within the range, it prints "INVALID Entry" (It continues, and does not break the program).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Even {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); int n= 0; int ec, oc = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter a number"); 
            n = sc.nextInt(); 
            ec= 0; oc = 0;

            switch(n){
                case 1: oc = 0;
                case 3:
                case 5:
                case 7:
                case 9: oc++; break;
                // Now Even
                case 2: ec = 0;
                case 4:
                case 6:
                case 8:
                case 10: ec++; break;

                default: System.out.print("Invalid Entry");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total number of even integers: " + ec + " and odd integers " + oc);
    }
}
```

The problem is, it gives the error: "ec might not have been initialised" at the end of the program at this line: "System.out.println("Total number of even integers: " + ec + " and odd integers " + oc);".

Why is this error caused? And how can this be fixed? Sorry if this appears silly, I am a novice and my intention is to learn. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near the top where you have this line -

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); int n= 0; int ec, oc = 0;
```

Change `int ec` to `int ec=0`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); int n= 0; int ec=0, oc = 0;
```

Also, you should all statements on separate lines -

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
int n= 0;
int ec, oc = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

prior to the for loop, initialize the variable `ec`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
int n= 0; 
int ec = 0, oc = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler requires that the local variable are initialized so that it does not accidentally try to read a value that is not assigned explicitly.

While you assign the value in your loop, the compiler doesn't find the initialization in the scope where the `System.out.println` resides, so it still complains. Just initialize the *ec* variable at the place you've declared it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `ec` is initialized inside `for` loop which may never be executed from the point of view of the compiler. In the statement `int ec, oc = 0;` only `oc` is initialized by `0`.